# How to calculate number of rows since last event

Tags: sql

The problem I'm trying to solve is I need to be able to count the number of cancelled visits between the current visit the last time a cancelled visit occurred.  The rows will have different Event Types between visits.  I need to identify on each Visit record, how many events happened since the last Visit.  Here is the data definition for the column:  # of missed appointment events since the previous visit

Here is what I NEED to happen

| CaseID | RefID | EventDT | EventType | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 90416201 | 20769471 | 1997-12-23 15:20:00.140 | New Appt | NULL |
| 90416201 | 20244038 | 1997-12-29 15:38:15.770 | Visit | 0 |
| 90416201 | 20246091 | 1997-12-31 00:08:41.047 | Cancel/Missed Appt | 0 |
| 90416201 | 20251620 | 1998-01-05 08:30:10.003 | Visit | 1 |
| 90416201 | 20773412 | 1998-01-12 08:24:04.473 | Visit | 0 |
| 90416201 | 20254300 | 1998-01-23 00:09:06.260 | Cancel/Missed Appt | 0 |
| 90416201 | 20795843 | 1998-01-23 09:14:08.687 | Visit | 1 |
| 90416201 | 20250871 | 1998-01-31 00:09:36.607 | Cancel/Missed Appt | 0 |
| 90416201 | 20269265 | 1998-02-03 08:27:21.010 | Cancel/Missed Appt | 1 |
| 90416201 | 20268562 | 1998-02-06 16:54:25.507 | Reschedule Appt | 0 |
| 90416201 | 20267840 | 1998-02-13 08:40:06.060 | Visit | 2 |
| 90416201 | 20826650 | 1998-02-13 10:11:58.630 | Checkpoint | 0 |
| 90416201 | 20835397 | 1998-02-20 09:03:09.820 | Visit | 0 |
| 90416201 | 20864419 | 1998-03-13 12:44:22.193 | Reschedule Appt | 0 |
| 90416201 | 20863805 | 1998-03-17 16:49:29.650 | Visit | 0 |
| 90416201 | 20272965 | 1998-03-19 00:09:17.363 | Cancel/Missed Appt | 0 |
| 90416201 | 25071224 | 2022-10-14 11:12:51.050 | Deleted Appt | 1 |

```
SELECT  90416201  AS CaseID,
        P1.ReferenceID,
        P1.EventDT,
        P1.EventType,
        (   SELECT  TOP (1) 1 AS EDT
            FROM    dbo.PADS_tmpWhs_CaseEvent_DEBUG AS P2
            WHERE   P2.CaseID = P1.CaseID
                    AND P2.EventDT < P1.EventDT
                    AND P2.EventTypeID = 3
            ORDER BY P2.EventDT DESC ) AS prevdt
FROM    <SOME TABLE> AS P1
ORDER BY P1.CaseID, 
    P1.EventDT
```

Here is what I get:

| CaseID | RefID | EventDT | EventType | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 90416201 | 20769471 | 1997-12-23 15:20:00.140 | New Appt | NULL |
| 90416201 | 20244038 | 1997-12-29 15:38:15.770 | Visit | NULL |
| 90416201 | 20246091 | 1997-12-31 00:08:41.047 | Cancel/Missed Appt | NULL |
| 90416201 | 20251620 | 1998-01-05 08:30:10.003 | Visit | 1 |
| 90416201 | 20773412 | 1998-01-12 08:24:04.473 | Visit | 1 |
| 90416201 | 20254300 | 1998-01-23 00:09:06.260 | Cancel/Missed Appt | 1 |
| 90416201 | 20795843 | 1998-01-23 09:14:08.687 | Visit | 1 |
| 90416201 | 20250871 | 1998-01-31 00:09:36.607 | Cancel/Missed Appt | 1 |
| 90416201 | 20269265 | 1998-02-03 08:27:21.010 | Cancel/Missed Appt | 1 |
| 90416201 | 20268562 | 1998-02-06 16:54:25.507 | Reschedule Appt | 1 |
| 90416201 | 20267840 | 1998-02-13 08:40:06.060 | Visit | 1 |
| 90416201 | 20826650 | 1998-02-13 10:11:58.630 | Checkpoint | 1 |
| 90416201 | 20835397 | 1998-02-20 09:03:09.820 | Visit | 1 |
| 90416201 | 20864419 | 1998-03-13 12:44:22.193 | Reschedule Appt | 1 |
| 90416201 | 20863805 | 1998-03-17 16:49:29.650 | Visit | 1 |
| 90416201 | 20272965 | 1998-03-19 00:09:17.363 | Cancel/Missed Appt | 1 |
| 90416201 | 25071224 | 2022-10-14 11:12:51.050 | Deleted Appt | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

For the problem statement, two type of events are important - “Visit” and “Cancel/Missed Appt”.
Let’s create two separate columns marking them as 1 and others as 0.

Assuming the table name is P1.

```
SELECT CaseID,
       ReferenceID,
       EventDT,
       EventType,
       CASE WHEN EventType = ‘Visit’ THEN 1 ELSE 0 END is_new_visit,
       CASE WHEN EventType = ‘Cancel/Missed Appt’ THEN 1 ELSE 0 END is_cancelled_visit
  FROM P1;
```

Now, traversing bottom-up, starting from the last visit, we want same value to be given to all records until previous visit record  we can achieve this by taking cumulative sum of “is_new_visit” column in descending order of Event Date.

```
SELECT temp1.*,
       SUM(is_new_visit) OVER (PARTITION BY CaseId ORDER BY EventDT) grip
  FROM (
      SELECT CaseID,
             ReferenceID,
             EventDT,
             EventType,
             CASE WHEN EventType = ‘Visit’ THEN 1 ELSE 0 END is_new_visit,
             CASE WHEN EventType = ‘Cancel/Missed Appt’ THEN 1 ELSE 0 END is_cancelled_visit
        FROM P1) temp1;
```

For each group, take the sum of “is_cancelled_visit”

```
SELECT temp2.*,
       SUM(is_cancelled_visit) OVER (PARTITION BY CaseId, grp) count_cancelled_since_last_visit
  FROM (
        SELECT temp1.*,
               SUM(is_new_visit) OVER (PARTITION BY CaseId ORDER BY EventDT) grp
          FROM (
              SELECT CaseID,
                     ReferenceID,
                     EventDT,
                     EventType,
                     CASE WHEN EventType = ‘Visit’ THEN 1 ELSE 0 END is_new_visit,
                     CASE WHEN EventType = ‘Cancel/Missed Appt’ THEN 1 ELSE 0 END is_cancelled_visit
                FROM P1) temp1
              ) temp2;
```

I’m expecting the result would look like this -

| CaseID | RefID | EventDT | EventType | is_new_visit | is_cancelled_visit | grp | count_cancelled_since_last_visit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 90416201 | 20769471 | 1997-12-23 15:20:00.140 | New Appt | 0 | 0 | 7 | 0 |
| 90416201 | 20244038 | 1997-12-29 15:38:15.770 | Visit | 1 | 0 | 7 | 0 |
| 90416201 | 20246091 | 1997-12-31 00:08:41.047 | Cancel/Missed Appt | 0 | 1 | 6 | 1 |
| 90416201 | 20251620 | 1998-01-05 08:30:10.003 | Visit | 1 | 0 | 6 | 1 |
| 90416201 | 20773412 | 1998-01-12 08:24:04.473 | Visit | 1 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
| 90416201 | 20254300 | 1998-01-23 00:09:06.260 | Cancel/Missed Appt | 0 | 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 90416201 | 20795843 | 1998-01-23 09:14:08.687 | Visit | 1 | 0 | 4 | 1 |
| 90416201 | 20250871 | 1998-01-31 00:09:36.607 | Cancel/Missed Appt | 0 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 90416201 | 20269265 | 1998-02-03 08:27:21.010 | Cancel/Missed Appt | 0 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 90416201 | 20268562 | 1998-02-06 16:54:25.507 | Reschedule Appt | 0 | 0 | 3 | 2 |
| 90416201 | 20267840 | 1998-02-13 08:40:06.060 | Visit | 1 | 0 | 3 | 2 |
| 90416201 | 20826650 | 1998-02-13 10:11:58.630 | Checkpoint | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 90416201 | 20835397 | 1998-02-20 09:03:09.820 | Visit | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 90416201 | 20864419 | 1998-03-13 12:44:22.193 | Reschedule Appt | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 90416201 | 20863805 | 1998-03-17 16:49:29.650 | Visit | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 90416201 | 20272965 | 1998-03-19 00:09:17.363 | Cancel/Missed Appt | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 90416201 | 25071224 | 2022-10-14 11:12:51.050 | Deleted Appt | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |